# How to evenly divide a tuple against an integer in a second argument in python?

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to create a function that has a set of integers in a tuple for the first argument, then an integer as the second argument, then divides the set of numbers in the tuple by the integer from the second argument, but returns only the numbers that were not able to be evenly divisible.

I started with something like this:

```
    def tuple_function(numbers, integers):
        numbers = (20, 35, 61, 80)
        integers = 10
    for i in numbers:
        if numbers[i] % integer == 0
           print(numbers)
```

Comment: So where do you get stuck?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything; it *writes* the numbers to standard output.

Comment: You passed `numbers` as 1st argument and in your function block you are assigning it to `(20, 35,...)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def tuple_function(numbers, divisor):
    return [i for i in numbers if i % divisor]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what format you want the numbers to return, so I'm going to assume you want it as a list. If not, it should be a quick change to something else. In that case, we can define it as a simple list comprehension, where you're looking to return each element in numbers if that element ('i') is divisible by your integer.

```
def tuple_function(numbers, integers):
    return [i for i in numbers if i%integer == 0]
```

When you define the function that way and run it, these are your results:

```
[IN]
numbers = (20, 35, 61, 80)
integers = 10
divisible = tuple_function(numbers, integers)
print(divisible)

[OUT]
[20, 80]
```

A couple things to watch for/clean up that can help you focus on the problem itself instead of any other errors you might be getting:

1. Don't define your arguments inside your function
2. You have 'integers' instead of integer on the third line
3. Don't forget your semicolon after your if statement on the second to last line.
4. In that if statement, remember that you defined i as "i in numbers'. This means that i will stand for the element of the tuple itself and not the index, so you just need 'i' in your last line and not 'numbers[i]'

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def tuple_function(numbers, integer):
    result = []
    for num in numbers:
        if num % integer != 0:
            result.append(num / integer)
    return result
```

(You could also make this much smaller using list comprehension)

```
def tuple_function(numbers, integer):
    return [num / integer for num in numbers if num % integer != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in one liners :

```
def odd_num(div, *collection)
    return [_ for _ in collection if not _ % divisor]
```

The syntax `*collection` assure that the argument given is a tuple.
The : `not _ % divisor` is a shortcut to take the number which the rest from the module operation is 0.
Call it in this way:

```
odd_num(10, 20, 35, 61, 80)
```

Or if you want pass list or tuple:

```
odd_num(10, *[20, 35, 61, 80])
odd_num(10, *(20, 35, 61, 80))
```